# Can I define the projection of a GeoTIFF using another GeoTIFF file as a template?

Tags: gdal

I would like to use the projection parameters of an existing GeoTIFF file as a template to define the projection of other GeoTIFFs. Is this possible with GDAL?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to see a ready made automatic system, like

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "the same as in image xyz.tif" input.tif output.tif
```

then no, that's not supported but it should not be hard to write a Python script for that. The script should just read the spatial reference system from the template image and insert it as target srs. Manually this can be done for example with  gdalsrsinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalsrsinfo.html and gdalwarp.

```
gdalsrsinfo mars.tif

PROJ.4 : +proj=longlat +a=3396190 +rf=169.894447223612 +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
GEOGCRS["GCS_Mars_2000",
    DATUM["D_Mars_2000",
        ELLIPSOID["Mars_2000_IAU_IAG",3396190,169.894447223612,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

Then you can use the same projection with gdalwarp

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -t_srs "+proj=longlat +a=3396190 +rf=169.894447223612 +no_defs" input.tif output.tif
```